Como migrar una base de datos mysql de su version 5.7.4 a la version 8.0.40?
esta es mi primera pregunta en el mundo del stack overflow :).
Me encuentro en un dilema, que sinceramente es la primera vez con algo así.
Recién ingrese a un nuevo trabajo como Jefe de Desarrollo, anterior a mi la persona encargada tenia muy mal los procesos y desarrollaba todo sin ningún control de versiones o compatibilidades y la cosa es la siguiente.
Hay una aplicación web donde se manejan unos cursos, esta aplicación es bastante transcurrida y tiene mucho flujo de usuarios al día por ende la base de datos es extremadamente grande, casi 600Gb de datos, tiene MYSQL 5.7.4 y esta desarrollada con Moodle y PHP 7.3 con WordPress.
El dilema es que hace poco con mi equipo, empezamos el desarrollo de una nueva app la cual ya finalizamos, para esta usamos un stack de tecnologías (tanto de front como back) que son actuales, lo cual al momento de hacer un despliegue en el servidor nos genero problemas por la versión de Mysql
El servidor tiene la version 5.7.4
Y necesitamos la version 8.0++
En el servidor se puede hacer la actualización de la versión de mysql, pero no lo hago por que la base de datos de la app de Moodle es gigantesca y la verdad me da miedo llegar a dañarla.
Entonces quiero saber si hay alguna forma segura de migrar esta base de datos con esa versión de MYSQL 5.7.4 a 8.0+, sin afectar la integridad de mis datos.
Les agradezco mucho me compartan sus conocimiento y experiencia en el tema.
Digamos que he intentado descargar la base de datos en su archivo .sql pero pues es casi imposible por esto no he modificado nada mas de ahí.

Esa actualización de versión puede generar ciertos problemas si no lo realizas de la forma correcta. Inicialmente, yo en tu lugar, realizaría un mantenimiento y depuración a esa base de datos, asumiendo que tiene datos muy antiguos o innecesarios. Segundo, en una ocasión tuve que subir justo a esas versiones que indicas y el cambio mas significativo (parece tonto, pero no) es el cambio del nombre en el driver usado para la conexión a la BD ya que si no lo especificas en los parámetros de tu conexión puede ocasionarte fallos. En mi caso (con Java) el nombre cambió a `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'.

Puedes leer un poco mas sobre esto en esta pregunta.

te recomiendo instalar el mysqlshell y utlilizar el mysqlchecker para ver que debes modificar o cambiar antes de la migracion...upgrade checker

Yo tengo una duda. Se podría hacer un Dump de la estructura de la DB sin datos? Navicat me permite hacer eso y ya con la estructura (solo la estructura) poder realizar los cambios y luego pasar la data tabla por tabla?? Digo, es solo duda, se que hay mejores y más optimar formas, pero a la rápida se me ocurre eso y no quería morir con la duda

@ErnestoRincon La db es bastante grande entonces me he dado en la tarea de borrar datos viejos, mi principal dificultad es el tamaño de esa db ;,,)

@OCHOA Sip, de hecho casualmente cuando recién vi el problema se me ocurrió  esto, el dilema es la cantidad de datos era mucha entonces tenia que esperar mucho tiempo para poder pasar los datos de una tabla a otra

@DanielRodriguez pero no te pueden exigir cambios como esos en X tiempo. Sea cual sea la mejor opción para hacer el update de la DB, el tiempo no creo que sea lo primordial. Porque si actualizas la estructura de la DB (basándonos en mi idea) y luego haces un volcado de datos tabla por tabla, aunque no sea "la opción más optima" daría igual. Creo que como nuevo jefe de desarrollo deberías dejar claro que las mejoras de un sistema como el que tienen no se deben "acelerar tanto" y que los cambios deben ser graduales y que obviamente tomarán su tiempo. Es mi percepción/opinión nada mas

Concuerdo 100% con @OCHOA , hay que procesos que toman su tiempo, y querer ahorrarse una o dos semanas puede resultar en una catástrofe. Hay que educar al usuario ajeno a TI que todo proceso tiene un tiempo mínimo de ejecución. Ya con que empieces a depurar la BD es un gran paso, identifica las tablas mas problemáticas y empieza por ahí (Siempre en ambiente de desarrollo).
